# How to change the title of the vlc mediaplayer window, of the module vlc which is imported as pip install python-vlc

Tags: python, python-vlc

I'm trying to change the title of the vlc mediaplayer window.

I searched in the documentation of python-vlc module and it seems there's no function that lets me change that, but maybe you know and can tell me.

this is the title that I want to change:
[image]